# Using a template

Tags: c++, templates

I've been trying to get a template that converts the characters in a string to upper case letters.

I need to do this several times throughout my program.

So i'll use a template.

```
template <string theString>
string strUpper( string theString )
{
    int myLength = theString.length();
    for( int sIndex=0; sIndex < myLength; sIndex++ )
    {
        if ( 97 <= theString[sIndex] && theString[sIndex] <= 122 )
        {
        theString[sIndex] -= 32;
        }
    }   
   return theString;
}
```

now only if the template worked!
Any Suggestions? The 'string' identifier should be an immediate flag.

Comment: Why does this need/do you want this to be a template?

Comment: Daniel L is right -- just delete the top line (making strUpper() a regular non-template function) and everything will work how you want.

Answer (score 7):

You apparently talk about `C++` (no tags yet, so i'll think it is C++ here). Well you seem to want to say

> As arguments to my template, i accept any type that *models a string*

Sadly, currently that is not possible yet. It requires the `concept` feature that will be in the next C++ version. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ot4WdHAGSGo) is a video about them.

What you can do is accept `basic_string<CharT, TraitsT>` if you want to keep it generic, for example if you want to accept wide character strings aswell as narrow character strings

```
template <typename CharT, typename TraitsT>
std::basic_string<CharT, TraitsT> strUpper(basic_string<CharT, TraitsT> theString ) {
    typedef basic_string<CharT, TraitsT> StringT;
    for(typename StringT::iterator it = theString.begin(); 
        it != theString.end(); 
        ++it) 
    {
        *it = std::toupper(*it, std::locale());
    }   
    return theString;
}
```

It will not accept other or custom string classes that happen to be *strings* too. If you want that, keep it totally free of what it accepts and what not

```
template <typename StringT>
StringT strUpper(StringT theString) {
    for(typename StringT::iterator it = theString.begin(); 
        it != theString.end(); 
        ++it) 
    {
        *it = std::toupper(*it, std::locale());
    }   
    return theString;
}
```

You will have to tell the users of that library what functions and type they have to expose for that to work. The compiler will not know about that contract. Instead, it will just throw error messages when it comes to call the function with a type that's not a string. Often, you will find pages of error messages and it's difficult to get to the real reason of what goes wrong. The proposed Concepts feature for the next version of the standard fixes that nicely.

If you did *not* intend to write such a generic function, you can just go ahead and write a normal function like this

```
std::string strUpper(std::string theString) {
    for(std::string::iterator it = theString.begin(); 
        it != theString.end(); 
        ++it) 
    {
        *it = std::toupper(*it, std::locale());
    }   
    return theString;
}
```

If you did *not* intend to invent that function to learn in the first place, but because you did not find another already written algorithm, look into the boost [string algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) library. Then you can write

```
boost::algorithm::to_upper(mystring);
```

Comment: Pass std::string by const ref.

Comment: i will have to copy it anyway. it's better to take it by value because that will be more transparent to the caller and can be better optimized.

Comment: if i could optimize anything i could think of, then it's to create the locale object locally and always reuse it. right now i always create a new temporary one. but i think that are implementation questions. the guy will put it on the stack in his program.

Comment: in a real program i would probably do what the standard recommends: caching the ctype facet and its toupper function, saving the facet for later use: locale loc; ctype<T> const& c = use_facet< ctype<T> >(loc); c.toupper(a) . This answer should show him the rough way i didn't want to bloat it :)